# SQL Server - 'NOT NULL' Constraint redundant on Primary Key?

Tags: sql, constraints

In the below SQL code is 'NOT NULL' redundant since f_ID is a primary key and thus can't be null for any record?

```
CREATE TABLE t_Activities(
    f_ID varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (f_ID))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you later drop the primary key constraint? Should the column allow nulls or not after that? Yes, no, maybe? The two constraints are different. PK constraint *requires* a NOT NULL, but does not *implies* one.

Answer (score 1):

It may be redundant, but I prefer this method of creating a `primary key` (or `Identity` column).  It shows that the person making the table understands and intends the column to be `NOT NULL` as well as the `Primary Key` for the table.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct.  If you had:

```
CREATE TABLE t_Activities( 
    f_ID varchar(50), 
    PRIMARY KEY (f_ID))
```

It would be the equivalen.  The Primary Key constraint does not allow `NULL`s.